# How to load an XML file in JavaScript, get specific info from it, and then display it through alert()?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

So, I want to make a program that will be able to get user data(a ton of bug names separated by commas), go through, get data for each one, then display all of that data in a table. I have been through rewriting this like 5 times and still nothing happens. Anyone know what is wrong with this code?

**My html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1 align="center">Bugs</h1>
  <p>In the area below, type in each of the insects you want information 
about, seperate them with a comma.</p>
  <textarea id="insects"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="go">Find out!</button>
  <br>
  <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {
var input = document.getElementById('insects').value;
var splitted = input.split(',');
for (i = 0; i<splitted.length; i++) {
    var bug1 = splitted[i];
    var part1 = // I need to assign it to bug1 without any whitespace
    var finish = part1.toLowerCase();
    find1(bug1);
  }
}
function find1(bug) {
  var xmlDocument = $.parseXML("externalfile:drive-77136639a78ffb21e72c7c4dfe7f7bb73604aeb3/root/Bugs/bugs.xml");
  var pain = $(xmlDocument).find("value[type='" + bug + "'] pain").text();
  alert(pain); <!-- This is to see if it works -->
}
  </script>
</body>
```

Here is my XML code(btw the XML file is called `bugs.xml` and yes they are in the same exact folder in `My Drive/Bugs`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bugs>
  <bug type="blisterbeetle">
    <name>Blister Beetle</name>
    <pain>55</pain>
    <conservation></conservation>
    <habitat></habitat>
    <rarity></rarity>
    <class></class>
    <order></order>
    <family></family>
    <species></species>
    <dangerous></dangerous>
    <external></external>
  </bug>
</bugs>
```

Comment: ?? `externalfile:drive-77` So you are loading it from file protocol? Did you look at error message in the console?

Comment: you need to have a separate `script` tags, one for your `src` and one for your inline code.

Comment: `externalfile:drive-77136639a78ffb21e72c7c4dfe7f7bb73604aeb3/root/Bugs/bugs.xml` appears to be a URL, in a scheme I've never heard of … and not a string of XML.

Comment: I tried a separate script but could not run the function from one to the other, and I looked in the console and there was no error.  :(

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn is right. Whatever other problems you have, you **must** use separate `script` elements to reference an external JS file and to encapsulate local script.